# Качественные и относительные прилагательные.

Tags: морфология

Как вы считаете, к какому разряду следует отнести  ниже приведенные прилагательные?

**Волчий аппетит, заячья трусость, лисья хитрость, отцовский дом, толстовские рассказы.**

Answer (score 3):

Волчий аппетит (перен.) - качественное, ср.: волчий хвост (прямое значение)- притяжательное; заячья трусость, лисья хитрость  - качественные, если значение переносное; отцовский дом - относительное (ср. отцов дом - притяжательное), толстовские рассказы - притяжательное.

Прилагательные на -ий, -иный в современном русском языке обозначают обычно свойство, присущее тому или иному живому существу. Эта семантическая особенность позволяет данным прилагательным сравнительно легко **переходить в разряд относительных и даже качественных** прилагательных. Например: ***медвежья берлога, волчий хвост*** - притяжательные прилагательные; ***медвежья услуга, волчий аппетит - качественные*** прилагательные и т.д. [здесь](http://www.hi-edu.ru/e-books/xbook107/01/part-073.htm)

Answer (score 2):

Отцовский дом, толстовские рассказы относятся к притяжательным прилагательным, которые обозначают принадлежность какого-либо предмета определенному лицу или (реже) животному: отцов, сестрин, Лизин, кошкин и др. Притяжательными являются и прилагательные на -ий, -ья, -ье: олений, лисья, козье (с суффиксом -j-). В отличие от притяжательных прилагательных на -ин, -нин, -ов (-ев) они обозначают общую родовую принадлежность, а не принадлежность одному лицу или животному.
Притяжательные прилагательные могут переходить в разряд относительных и качественных. Волчий аппетит, заячья трусость, лисья хитрость имеют качественное значение: волчий хвост (хвост принадлежит волку,притяж. прил., но волчий аппетит (качест. прил.) - аппетит как у волка и т. д.

Comment: Отцовский дом - это относительное прилагательное. Отцовский дом может принадлежать не отцу.

Comment: Вряд ли это весомая причина для объявления прилагательного относительным. Я думаю, что правильнее будет сказать, что в данном случае прилагательное приобретает контекстные признаки относительного. Грамматическая притяжательность при этом под сомнение не ставится.  
Иначе придется пересмотреть разряды у бОльшей части подобных прилагательных, допускающих употребление в переносном или обобщенном значении.

Answer (score 1):

Волчий аппетит - сильный аппетит-качественное, заячья трусость-относящаяся к зайцу, как у зайца - может быть и относительным (напрягала заячья трусость товарища),и притяжательным (мы наблюдали за зайцем. и заячья трусость вызывала улыбку); лисья хитрость - то же самое: лисья хитрость подруги(относительное), но лисья хитрость= хитрость самой лисы(притяжат.); отцовский дом = принадлежит отцу, отцов, отчий(устар.) - притяжательное,даже если он просто родной, всё равно ассоциация с принадлежностью отцу, роду; толстовские рассказы - рассказы Толстого - притяжательное. Чётких границ и быть не может, если есть такое явление, как многозначность.Нужно вдумываться в смысл - это прямое качество, характеристика через качество другого предмета или принадлежность предмету. Вот фиолетовый, коричневый, карий, сиреневый - в классическом случае не имеют степеней сравнения и краткой формы,потому что произошли от существительных, но они качественные, вот у символистов находим: "И плащ его фиолетов", "сиренево мелькали...","пиджак коричнев".И воспринимается вполне нормально, образно.Значит, качественные, ведь цвет обозначают качественные прилагательные.

Comment: Вы только скажите, Людмила, в чем практический и теоретический смысл подобных классификационных **различений**, когда одно и то же слово относят к трем разным видам? Не зряшная ли это **суета**...

"Оранжевые мамы оранжево поют")))

Comment: Вот-вот-оранжево, значит, качественное.Почему у одного и того же слова есть разные значения, а одно прилагательное не может относиться к разным категориям? Категории-то эти - лексико - грамматические, значение там - определяющий признак, грамматика- добавочный. Шахматов вон вообще не говорил о категориях, он говорил о грамматических группах, а  по значению за всеми прилагательными  закреплял признак качества. Он в класс притяжательных прилагательных не включает  прилагательные на -ий, -ский, а рассматривает как притяжательные только прилагательные на -ов, -ин.Может, так было понятнее.

Comment: Насчёт зряшной суеты - согласна. Но учёным-то диссертации защищать надо? Вот они и "двигают"науку. Студенты приходят за помощью - я терминов-то их не знаю, говорю:"Давай лекции".А фонематическая транскрипция?-кошмар.Фонетической для учителя и учеников вполне хватает, но...наука идёт вперёд - и мы её не остановим, придётся учить, что они там напридумают. А насчёт прилагательных - я бы на Шахматове остановилась - другие только запутали. Категории нужны только для правильного изменения , разделить по группам окончаний - и хватит.